# How to send CTRL+C WITH JSCH?

Tags: c, jsch, ctrl

I'm using `jsch ChannelShell` to send commands to a remote system, but I can't send special commands like `ctrl+c`. I tried many things, but have no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you have for opening this channel and sending the ctrl-c.

Comment: Have you tried to send the Hex 03 or ETX?

Comment: Actullay, i realized, i could send ctrl+c with Hex 03 (tried it while tail command is running). But, while cat command is running for a big file, i couldn't stop it with same way. What is the reason of that?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply send a signal.
In your case it will be 2 which corresponds to CTRL+C :

```
channel.sendSignal("2"); // sends (CTRL+C) signal
```

You can find list of Unix signals [here](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

I think, i figured out my fault. Cat and grep(and those type of commands) commands are one shot commands. They are not continuous. So I can't interrupt those commands. I have to stop listening stream to stop printing outputs.

Comment: No wait! They ARE continuous and of course you can kill them by sending a SIGINT. They usually fulfill the output buffer and quit before the buffer is actually shown at console.. but yes, before stop listening you should stop them

Answer (score 0):

if you want to terminate an operation like tail

```
Example -    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ce.getInputStream()));
         OutputStream out=ce.getOutputStream();
out.write(3); //terminate the tail command

 out.flush();
```

Comment: Please format your code (Ctrl + K) and add some descriptive text why this answer is helpful for the questioner